# How to check if value is undefined and if it is, set it to null

Tags: javascript, variables, null, undefined

```
value = value ? value : null;
```

I want to set `value` to `null` if it is `undefined`. Beside what I already have written, what else I can do with less repeating and more clean?

Comment: `value = value || null;` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), which is a *"[...] logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand"*:

```
value = value ?? null;
```

This best fits your requirements to assign `null` when `value` is `undefined`.
In combination with the assignment, this can be made even more concise by using the [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) operator (`??=`):

```
value ??= null;
```

This should meet all your requirements, but let's also look at some possible alternatives:

#### Logical OR operator (`||`)

Another alternative could be the `||` operator:

```
value = value || null;
```

Or in its [assignment form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment):

```
value ||= null;
```

The difference here is that `null` will be assigned for any [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, including `0`, `false`, and `''`.

#### Ternary operator (`?:`)

This is the original implementation from your question:

```
value = value ? value : null;
```

Essentially, this exhibits the same problem as the logical OR operator implementation in the sense that `null` will be assigned for any *falsy* value. In this case, however, this can be mitigated by including a stricter comparison in the ternary condition (making it even more verbose):

```
value = value != null ? value : null;
```

Comment: *"This is closer to your requirements"* It'd worth adding a bit more information about that.

Comment: There is also the [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) `??=` since OP mentioned less repeating, eg `value ??= null`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Totally forgot about that one, will update to include it.

Comment: @FelixKling I think I've covered it now. Let me know if something's missing.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `Nan` and `''` are considered as a **falsy statement**, so if you want to make sure that you update your variable only if  it holds an `undefined` value you should consider using an **if statement** like this
`if(value==undefined) value =null;`